# Boot Repair says SFS detected so is it safe to continue or will harmful?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, grub

I had having trouble installing grub of linux so I perform Boot Repair to do but now appearing this message:

> SFS detected.
>   You may want to retry after converting Windows dynamic partitioning (SFS partitions) to a basic disk.
>   This can be performed via tools such as TestDisk or EASEUS-Partition-Master / MiniTool-Partition-Wizard.
>   Do you want to continue?

So may I ignore this message and continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply just performed **Boot Repair**
With **Advanced options**
[image]

**Main options**
Check Reinstall Grub under Main options tab
**GRUB location**
Select Linux Distribution from OS to boot by default under GRUB location tab 
and
Check Place GRUB into: to Disk in which your linux distro is installed.
for example sdx, sdy, sdz.
**GRUB options**
Check Purge GRUB before reinstalling it
**MBR options tab will be disabled**
**Other options**
Check Place the boot flag on: and select your linux distribution that is listed
and press Apply button.
There was an error after it done but this installed grub and other OS win 7 also was added to grub.